# Де ще можна вживати прийменник «уві»?

Tags: граматика, прийменники

Хто з експертів української мови знає, де ще можна вживати прийменник «уві» окрім як виразу «уві сні»?

Comment: Стаття "Кремль уві млі" http://www.golos.com.ua/article/252285 Також у словнику СУМ-11 є декілька прикладів: http://sum.in.ua/s/v (наприклад з чумацької пісні: "Та вдарили зразу в дзвони уві всі")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не знавець, але правопис 2019 наводе:

> **§ 23. Уживання прийменників *у*, *в* і початкових *у-*, *в-***
>
> 1. Щоб уникнути збігу букв на позначення приголосних звуків, що є важкими для вимови, та щоб досягти милозвучності, в українській мові вживають на письмі прийменник **у** і початковий **у-**:
>
>    2. На початку речення або слова перед буквою на позначення приголосного: […]
>
>       <sup>[**Примітка  2.**](//files.nas.gov.ua/PublicMessages/Documents/0/2021/01/210118223223523-1428.pdf#page=26) Перед двома і більше буквами на позначення приголосних можливі варіанти прийменників **уві**, **вві** та початкових **уві-**, **вві-**: *…**уві** сні бачив [Артем] батька* (А. Головко); *Згасала зірка **уві** млі* (П. Воронько); […]</sup>
>
>    5. Незалежно від кінця попереднього слова перед **в**, **ф**, а також перед буквосполученнями **льв-**, **зв**-, **св-**, **дв-**, **тв-**, **гв-**, **хв-** та ін.: […]

Тобто коли наступне слово ся починає з 2+ приголосних, а попереду приголосний або початок речення.

Якщо цїкаво приклади вживу, що [не завжди збіжне](//zbruc.eu/node/41931) з правилами, то можна просто поґуґлити чи полазити в корпусах, котрі часом можуть надати статістіку:

- [Лайпціґ](//corpora.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%96): *млі*, *Львові*, *тьмі*, *злі*.
- [Ґрач](//parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac15&tab=advanced&keyword=%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%96&attrs=word%2Clemma&viewmode=sen&attr_allpos=kw&refs_up=1&shorten_refs=0&itemsPerPage=500&structs=s%2Cg&refs=%3Ddoc.author%2C%3Ddoc.date%2C%3Ddoc.title%2C%3Ddoc.translator%2C%3Ddoc.uri%2C%3Ddoc.mediaName&default_attr=lemma&showresults=1&results_screen=collocations&fullcontext=1&f_tab=advanced&c_cfromw=1&c_ctow=1&c_itemsPerPage=200&c_showresults=1&c_customrange=1&operations=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22iquery%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%96%22%2C%22active%22%3Atrue%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22queryselector%22%3A%22iqueryrow%22%2C%22iquery%22%3A%22%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%96%22%7D%2C%22id%22%3A8523%7D%5D): *млі*, *тьмі*, *Львові*.

Тобто вжиток дуже малий і лише з певними словами, хоча слів з двома приголосними вистачає. Навіть якщо відкинути *в* → *у* (див. вище 23.1.5), нп. *у Львові*, то *ві*, навіть попри жодної згадки в правописї (зате є церковнословянське [*во*](//files.nas.gov.ua/PublicMessages/Documents/0/2021/01/210118223223523-1428.pdf#page=27)!), втч. *ві Львові*, буде вживанїшим. Виняток лише *уві сні*, бо це вже як сталий вираз, але запис *ві сні* теж існує.